# Loading shared object to specific processes in Linux

Tags: process, kernel-modules, shared-library

I want to load a shared object to certain processes, there are certain conditions that are required

- loading to only specific processes and not all of them
- it has to be done before the process code starts executing
- the processes are not mine

What are the available ways to support this functionality on Linux?

Can it be accomplished with "/etc/ld.so.preload" or "LD_PRELOAD=/my/lib.so"? Is a kernel module needed for this?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code you can use is something like:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/my/lib.so /path/to/binary
```

If this library is required for binary you can use also:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH /path/to/binary
```

and the binary will search for this library in path `/my` before searching in standard paths

Comment: thanks @Romeo Nivov.
can it be used when I'm not the one who executes the target processes? I couldn't verify that in the Linux manual for LD_*

Comment: What do you mean by " I'm not the one who executes the target processes"? You can use this with `sudo`, in init scripts, etc.

Comment: I mean for processes created by others (e.g. the OS, other exes), not by my scripts or me as a user with "sudo"...

Comment: if they execute the command on this way (as shown above) they will have it. If you want to force everyone on the server on every program to have this you can use  `/etc/ld.so.preload`

Comment: I want it only for selected programs and not all of them (the list is dynamic and managed  elsewhere) and automatic so I won't have to manually force "LD_*" on users/programs.
thanks!

Comment: You can replace the actual program with shell script which do the load. Do you want to hide the fact of load this library?

Comment: I don't have to hide the library, but I probably should